# How to implement UnitOfWork with Entity Framework (and other ORMs). Some data in DB, some in memory

Tags: .net, entity-framework, validation, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

**Changed from:** *"Domain Model validation with Entity Framework (and other ORMs). Some data in DB, some in memory."*

Initially I thought that implementing UoW with EF is an easy task. But it turned out to be a lot trickier.

When Business Logic (wherever it resides) asks repository for the entity, it should search not only in Database but in local cache as well. Repository should not return entity in case it is marked for deletion within current UoW, yet it still exists in the storage.
It is partial graph materialization what brings complexity. There's no question when we forget about persistence and pretend that everything lives in memory: load everything, change it as you like and then write resultant changes to db. As easy as it gets.

*To add more specifics:*
Authentication message handler sets the Principal.
Somewhere deep in my BL I need to check whether current authenticated user can perform the action.
Each role has actions assoicated with it. So I need to find all roles with the action and check user is in role. However, there is a chance that during processing the request the user has been removed from role. This information about removal (or addition) is held inside UoW but not persited yet. So if my checking logic asks DB only it can get the answer which is inconsistent with the workflow.

Probably I'm wrongly setting the boundary of UoW and it should not cross separate BL operation:
- Remove user from role - changes went to DB
- Check user roles - get state from DB

Though BL can have nested calls with each writing to DB. So I feel it's ok to let the client define the "size" of UoW.

Fowler [describing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) UoF says:

> You can change the database **with each change to your object model**,
>   but this can lead to lots of very small database calls, which ends up
>   being very slow. Furthermore it requires you to have a transaction
>   open for the whole interaction, which is impractical if you have a
>   business transaction that spans multiple requests. The situation is
>   even worse if you need to keep track of the objects you've read so you
>   can avoid inconsistent reads.

But behaviour can require sequence of object changes. And each change must know about the current state - the state after previous changes which have not been stored in DB yet.

**The original wording of the question:**

I'm slightly confused with Repository and Unit of Work pattern implemented with Entity Framework.

First, I allow my model to be in an invalid state until Commit() phase of UnitOfWork.
The simplest example of why this is benefitial is a move and rename file semantics.
[image]

If case you need to move `file1` to `Dir2` and rename it to `file2` there is no easy way to do it if you have transactionally separate *move* and *rename* operations.
There is a naming confict either in `Dir1` or `Dir2`.

So I see it reasonalbe to allow model temporarily have invalid state.

Now the **essence of my problem :**

My business model have the rule which requires all related entities to be analyzed.
I put the validation logic inside parent entity which logically contains all these items and thus responsible for imposing and checking constraints. And I'd also like to check uniqueness constraints as well.

That may sound a bit paranoid but in this case I can check my logic easily with unit tests even not using Database.

However at the moment EF starts validation process "future" system's state is defined both by current context (Added,Deleted,Modified iteme) and the part which was not materialized into memory and stayed in db (let alone the concurrency). (There is absolutely no to loading all entities into memory).

This requires my Repository to be quite elaborate to take the fact of distributred state into account. I found this to be quite not a trivial task.

I'd like to know how other people solved this. May be there are better approaches to this problem.

Comment: What you're describing is known as 'Eventual Consistency' or 'BASE'.  It's an alternative view on consistency that's less rigid than 'Transactions' or 'ACID'.  Googling some of these terms should help you find answers, as a solution would be very subjective to your current approaches (i.e. are you doing CQRS?).

Comment: Well' I'm more in research of DDD parttern rather than active implementation. As soon as I approach persistance ignorance, Repository, UoW and the stuff like that DDD becomes very blurred.

Answer (score 1):

Actually DDD is very simple. It just means: model the Domain concepts, behaviour and uses cases in code. The ORM or ANY persistence (db) detail have no place here. When you do DDD, the db doesn't exist. WHen you want something to be stored you send it to a Repository. When you need something from storage, you ask the Repository to get it.

DDD is a mindset which emphasize focus on the business, rather than on technical bits. The Repository is the 'persistence', from the Domain point of view. Of course the Domain only defines the repo interface (abstraction) while the repository implementation resides elsewhere, usually in the Peristence layer. But you can have more than one implementation. When testing or simply developing is much easier to have an in memory repository (fast to write) good enough to act as a 'temporary' db but without involving an actual db. Of course, the Doamin doesn't really care about how the Repo is implemented and nor it should, because the point of the Repository is to **decouple** the Domain from the Persistence details.

So EF, Nhibernate, NoSql etc all these don't matter , the Domain only knows about a repository interface. The repo implementation will use all these tools, but the Domain won't know it.

ONe more thing, domain model validatin is done by the Domain. The repository doesn't do validation, it just saves/loads things from the db. If you're referring to user input validation, that should be done before the data enters the Domain, because it's about data formatting. However, everything related to business rules are enforced only by the Domain

Comment: The broblem is that to enforce business rules you might need to ask repository for related entities. But these entities exsit in DB and in memory so repo somehow should merge them to return consistent result. Sure, if you had only in-memory collections that would be no problem at all. May be I'd change quesion wording to "How to implement repo with EF to take into account an in-memory state.

Comment: There is no problem. Business rules are enforced only in Domain and you don't need to ask the repositories for related entities because there aren't any. Applying the rdbms mindset to DDD is VERY DANGEROUS and results in very bad domain modelling.The business rules are use case dependant and usually are part of a Service which will use different entities but this is not about FK type relationships.You're using the Repo because you don't care about memory or db storage.The repo interface and the Domain usage don't change regardless of the repo implementation.DDD starts with Domain, ends with db

Comment: How will you impose the rule of MaxOrdersCount for the customer in the method Customer.AddNewOrder()? Where to get the number of custemr's orders? Some orders are in DB, some are in UnitOfWork and marked as Added. The best thing is to ask repo isn't it? 
You could track this within Customer.OrdersCount property setting its initial value during Customer materailization then incrementing and decrementing it when needed. Yet I'm not you'l never need to ask repo of customer's orders to check some assertion.

Comment: Why does the Customer has an AddNewOrder method? It looks to me as an **use case** of the Customer not a **behaviour**. OrdersCount seems to be something outside the Customer definition, more part of OrderStats context. DDD is quite tricky and if you don't get the contexts right, it'll be a mess named DDD which has little in common with DDD.

Comment: Where would you put the behavior then?

Comment: Creating new order for the customer not forgetting about the rules the customer can have about its own orders.

Comment: I'd put it in a service which will take the relevant info from the a Customers Service. Things are not straightforward, it's not a recipe on how to do things. It greatly depends on the Domain, however as a guideline, a use case can define a bounded context with all the relevant models. One point is you don't need to put everything in one model. Create as many models you need that makes sense in those specific contexts. DDD is a mindset, not a methodology. It's up to you to identify the contexts and their models.

Answer (score 0):

Now I believe there's no generic way to implement repository.
Each case requires its own consideration.

Consider this piece of code:

```
public TEntity FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
{
    var compiledFilter = filter.Compile();

    var entity = DbSet.Local.SingleOrDefault(compiledFilter); // first, look in local storage
    if (entity != null)
    {
        return entity;
    }

    // Now we ask the database.
    entity = DbSet.SingleOrDefault(filter);

    // Entity from database can be already 'deleted' or changed locally. 
    // Modified local entity may not pass the filter so we should check this explicitly.
    if (entity != null && !MatchesLocal(entity, compiledFilter))
    {
        entity = null;
    }

    return entity;
}

private bool MatchesLocal(TEntity entity, Func<TEntity, bool> filter)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(entity != null);
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(filter != null);

    var entry = Context.Entry(entity);
    var deleted = entry.State == EntityState.Deleted;

    var result = !deleted && filter(entity);

    return result;
}
```

This somewhat corresponds to Fowler's repository [sequence diagram](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).
Alas, there are caveats. If filtering expression uses navigation properties and Lazy Load is off it's quite likely to get NullReferenceException. In case search is performed against properties non existent in DB there will be another exception.
Probably, expression transformation with special visitor allows to overcome this issue, yet it's not an easy task.

Next point is performance. When we just need to check something there's no sense in getting a bunch of objects.
Here is the example:

```
        public bool VendorExistsWithName(string vendorName)
        {
            vendorName = vendorName.ToLower();

            // look among local objects
            var matchedLocalVendors = DbSet.Local
                                           .Where(
                                               vendor =>
                                               vendor.Name.ToLower() == vendorName)
                                           .ToList();

            if (matchedLocalVendors.Count >= 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            var deletedVendorIds = new HashSet<int>(GetDeleted().Select(vendor => vendor.VendorId));
            var modifiedVendors = GetModified().ToDictionary(vendor => vendor.VendorId);

// ReSharper disable ReplaceWithSingleCallToAny 
            var exists = DbSet.Where(vendor => vendor.Name.ToLower() == vendorName)
                                  .Select(vendor => vendor.VendorId)
                                  .AsEnumerable()
                                  .Where(id => !deletedVendorIds.Contains(id)) // not deleted
                                  .Where(
                                      id =>
                                      !modifiedVendors.ContainsKey(id) ||
                                      modifiedVendors[id].Name.ToLower() == vendorName)
                                  .Any(); // matches even if modified
// ReSharper restore ReplaceWithSingleCallToAny

            return exists;
        }
```

Here we get only ids instead of large objects. The method can be generalized, however this requires effort to get and group entities by keys whatever they are (simple or composite).
All mentioned functionality could be provided by Entity Framework out of the box. Unfortunately, it is not.

And the last but not the least pain is situations where aggregate functions should but cannot be used. Without proper 'merge' of in-memory state with the state of DB it's close to impossible. On the other side I cannot remember the case where I wanted to use aggregate functions in my business logic.

So to summarise I'd like to tell that while implementing good and consistent repository with EF requires effort it is not so scary as initially seemed to me.